# How to add a website link which is not a cited paper in the bib file (bib database)

Tags: bibliographies

I made a bib file contains all the references which are a cited papers, but some of the references are links for a sites not papers, could you provide me by the way to describe them in my bib file database.

for example:

```
\bibitem{blablabla}
```

blabla, url: http://bla.org/ (2015).

In order to add it to the bib database, to be like this:

```
@article{Douglas20141246,
title = "....... (DBDDAS) Development ",
journal = "Procedia Computer Science ",
volume = "29",
number = "",
pages = "1246 - 1255",
year = "2014",
note = "2014 International Conference on Computational Science ",
issn = "1877-0509",
doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.procs.2014.05.112",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050914002890",
author = "Craig C. Douglas",
keywords = "Big data",
keywords = "DDDAS",
keywords = "dynamic data driven applications",
keywords = "open source software",
keywords = "sensor networks",
keywords = "uncertainty quantification",
keywords = "anomaly detection "
}
```

Comment: I would guess `\nocite{Opencv2}`. But of course this is untested.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I've updated my question

Comment: @eren how does Johannes' answer not solve you question? If it literally just is a website perhaps the misc type could be used. You can add the url to the note field. Remember to use `\url`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the IEEETrans package to format my bibliography. 
It accepts database item type `@electronic`
Here is an example entry

```
@electronic{wolfram,
  Ttile = {Feigenbaum Constant},
  Year = 2016,
  Month = {March},
  Author = {Weisstein, Eric W},
  Howpublished = {MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource},
  Url = {http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FeigenbaumConstant.html}
}
```

This will format as so:

[image: Example of citation using IEEETrans package]

It can read the Url field and knows how to split URLs without them looking terrible.

**Edit:** To have a date on as well. 
Here is the old one without a date:
[image: Example of citation using IEEETrans package]

Comment: The world wide web is as steady as a willow in the winds, you need a date as well.

Comment: Fixed, Thank you for pointing that out.
IEEETrans doesn't show the date as well though. Or not that I could determine